# Bubbling events from HTML elements down into iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an iframe that acts as a big button. The entire content inside of the iframe is one click target.

What I'd like to do is hover some piece of HTML over the iframe kind of like in this example.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            iframe {
                height: 100px;
                width: 300px;
            }
            div {
            position: relative;
            }
            a {
                 position: absolute;
                 top: 0;
                left: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <iframe src="frame.html"></iframe>
            <a id="text">Image</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can also see a live example here http://dev.gjcourt.com/iframe

The problem is that I'd like to have click events from the anchor bubble down into the iframe. Is there any way to make this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Position the iframe absolutely, make the background of the iframe transparent and give it a z-index higher than the text/other content.

Why are you using an iframe for this?

Comment: I need the iframe because the image uploading feature that utilizes the iframe must be xdomain, and minus HTML5 and the File API there is no reliable way to do xdomain asynchronous uploads.

Comment: This works! Thank you so much for the helpful reply. Now to see if it integrates into the product... Apologies for not upvoting, but I need a rep of 15 to do that.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of possible [Clickjacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking) and most browsers attempt to prevent it.

Comment: Kind of.. I'm not trying to do anything malicious. I need the click in an iframe to do something xdomain.

Comment: Though your intentions are good, the browser still has a responsibility to try to prevent it and any solution to circumvent that shouldn't be relied on (and should in fact be reported to the browser vendor).  Are you sure there is no API or similar on the site you're trying to access?

Comment: I happen to disagree with you. While Clickjacking should be avoided, my product is an embeddable widget, that someone has opted into putting on their website. The reason that I'm trying to do this is for localization, it would be nice to have a translatable string appear instead of a background image (also nice for font inheritance). Since someone has opted into using my product, and the button already exists inside the iframe (think facebook like button) than it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: If you're providing the page to be loaded within the iframe then you can provide customizability via URL parameters.

Answer (score 0):

As @Zikes mentioned this is a clickjacking attack, but it is still possible nowadays. All you need to do is to overlay your iframe with SVG element and set pointer-events="none", so it will flow all cursor events through SVG element down to iframe. You can find more examples and [crossbrowser solutions in this article](http://podlipensky.com/2012/07/clickjacking-explained/).